# how to copy&paste cleanly into grep?

Tags: shell, grep, echo, stdin, cat

I have some test output, looking like

```
PASS: tests/test_mutex_rmw
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

I want to filter the output to just view the failures.  It would be convenient to just copy&paste into stdin and pass into grep, e.g.

```
grep FAIL
```

and Shift-Ctrl-V (or middle mouse button) to copy the text in.

What I want to see is just

```
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

But instead, the input pasted in is displayed to screen, and because of buffering the input gets mixed with the final output:

```
$ grep FAIL
PASS: tests/test_mutex_rmw
PASS: tests/test_mutex_trylock
PASS: tests/test_malloc_irreg
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
PASS: tests/test_groups
PASS: tests/test_group_split
PASS: tests/test_malloc_group
FAIL: teFAIL: tests/ARMCI_PutS_latency
sts/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
FAIL: tests/ARMCI_AccS_latency
FAIL: tests/test_accs
FAIL: tests/test_accs_dla
```

It would make sense to me for the input to first be provided to cat and then passed to grep, `cat | grep FAIL`, but that doesn't actually help. The buffer mixup still occurs

It can be filtered cleanly if the data is placed in a file which is passed to grep.  But it would be more convenient to be able to do it simply by Copy&Paste from the terminal output. How is that best done?

Equivalently, how can pasting be done without echoing to screen (providing data silently as stdin for the command)?

Comment: Did you enter an EOF character (Control-D) to terminate your stdin?

Comment: Ctrl-D is a separate issue, it's needed to close the process. grep waits for it to end the program, but starts processing the input (mixing it with output) before Ctrl-D is given.

Comment: Of course it does, but where is the problem? If you don't like to see your output, redirect stdout to a file and inspect the file afterwards.

Comment: No, you have not understood the question.

Comment: Pasting something to a terminal application means first of all, that the terminal receives the input. This is unrelated to the program you are running. How is your terminal app supposed to know that you don't want to see the pasted data? It is equivalent to request to type something on the keyboard and ask the terminal not to echo the keys. Perhaps there are terminals which can be switched into such a "silent mode", but if they are, you better ask this at [su], because it is not really a programming question.

Comment: One idea which may work (I didn't try it): You could turn your terminal into non-echoing mode (`stty -echo; grep FAIL`).

Comment: That does work, thanks.  It leaves echo switched off, so the full solution would be
`stty -echo; grep FAIL; stty echo`
(with or without the round brackets).

I suspect there's more than one way of doing it, but this way works fine.

Comment: I just tried it too. On my system (which happens to be Cygwin), the echo is turned back on automatically after I typed the control-D and am back on the prompt. I suspect that my shell (zsh) turns on _echo_ before printing its prompt, and that this is the reason why I don't have to re-enable it.

Comment: What if the output of the command is longer than your terminal display length? For example, lets say your terminal is set to display up to 500 lines and your command outputs 1000 lines - doing this copy/paste from the window just can't work in that case so you may want to consider getting into the habit of doing `cmd | tee file; grep 'FAIL' file` or similar so you don't sometimes miss some of the output when trying to grep in it.

Comment: You're overthinking it, Ed.  I'm looking for a convenience tool, not an operations script. Avoiding the overhead of fiddling about with intermediary files is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

@user1934428's solution from the question discussion gets the job done:

```
stty -echo; grep FAIL; stty echo
```

I'm using bash, for which I need to switch echo back on.  Apparently zsh automatically sets echo back on at the next command prompt, in which case the closing command is not needed.

This solution works for me.  Would still be interested to hear if there are other solutions.

Comment: More solutions proffered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693720/